# Use Pick to construct a type for object with an index type

Tags: typescript

Given the following interface:

```
interface Foobar {
  things?: { [key: string]: string[] };
}
```

Can the [PickType](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys) be used to create a type for re-use?

```
// Manually typing it works:
// type Part { [key: string]: string[] }

// this does not:
type Part = Pick<Foobar, "things">;
const something: Part = { x: ["a", "b"] } };

Object.keys(something).forEach((thing) => {
  const needThis = something[thing];
  console.log(needThis); // <- this should return ["a", "b"]
});
```

Created a codesandbox with the example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-edison-ejck8?file=/src/index.ts

The code compiles, but with warnings:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Pick<Foobar, "things">'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Pick<Foobar, "things">'
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. What is the type of foobar - is it SomeInterface or Foobar? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Sorry about that. I'm having difficulty explaining. The someThing is the thing I'd like to type. Which is a partial of the interface Foobar.

Comment: No worries, thanks for updating the question. I believe Eldar's answer is what you need - Pick is useful to extract a 'slice' of an object - whereas you want just the type of some property. Unless we're misunderstanding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Pick` will create a subtype with the keys provided as the second argument. So in your example you will have a type like this :

```
type Something {
 someThing: { [key: string]: string[] };
}
```

**Edit**: As @mbdavis mentioned in the comments `Pick` seems completely redundant here :

If you want to use the type of property you should also provide the name of the property  like this :

```
type SomeInterface =  Foobar["someThing"]
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt0CM5WQbwChkxgwAbCALmQGcwpQBzAbmNvQFsIAVAC2Y18yANoBrCAE8a9RiCYBdGQ2YiFyAL5sNhQmEkAHFAGUuEAJLho8JMgC8yNJhxQRAIg7d+zNwt0J0EHo6M295ZBpTbktIWEQUB2EPMwBpKTcI0Tc4XwAaYmTuAHkwPmg0yQyI9yxfLV1kIqwAKwgEMAA6CUlaAApPXgF5AEoOmHQoAFFEPl7e7uRhuwA+IkdkAKD0Sg7ydCZ+0KGmcSkFYeINYaA)

Comment: Here  `Pick<Foobar, 'someThing'>["someThing"]` is equivalent to `Foobar["someThing"]`

Comment: Perfect! And if you'd like to make it mandatory as opposed to optional?

Comment: @Remi being optional or not won't affect the subtype `SomeInterface` since it belongs to the parent Interface's property. Sub interface just annotates the type definition.